# Software to tell what a cloud looks like?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

So, after [XKCD's Tasks comic](http://www.xkcd.com/1425/), Flickr created [a solution for the problem](http://parkorbird.flickr.com/) mentioned there. Now I'm interested whether is there a solution to the problem mentioned in the [Cloud comic](http://xkcd.com/1444/).

[image: Cloud computing has a ways to go.].

So is there a software that takes a picture of a cloud as an input and tells what that cloud looks like?

It doesn't matter if it is free or not, just looking for a software that solves this problem *somehow*. It should work just like how people do it in real life, so the answer for a cloud should make some kind of sense.

Comment: A Rohrschach test for a computer? OpenCV with a broad knowledge base could do that...